# Dynamically send n audio sources (concurrently ) to specifc channel on ASIO device

Tags: c#, audio, naudio, asio

So i have been having some fun exploring the NAudio lib.

However, I'm not sure whether I am missing something using the ASIO class. Basically my requirements are the following:

- Dynamically output (mono) sources to an ASIO device, each source to a dedicated channel (later on I will probably be working with 64 channels)
- Be free to 'stream' the n audio sources to the device at any time during the session (multiple sources simultaneously)
- Have the control over each channel

So in Code I'd have something like:

```
...

WaveFileReader source1 = new WaveFileReader( pathToMyFile1 );
WaveFileReader source2 = new WaveFileReader( pathToMyFile2 );
WaveFileReader source3 = new WaveFileReader( pathToMyFile3 );
...

WaveFileReader sourceN = new WaveFileReader( pathToMyFileN );

AsioOut out = new AsioOut();

...

/*Now init out...*/

...

out.Play();

...

/* now react on events, possibly within a multi-threaded enviroment*/
/* and concurrently send each of these sources to a dedicated channel*/
/* as required, (as stated, possibly even many at the same time) */

...
```

So my Question basically is:

Can I, using one of the existing classes, achieve something like this? Or will I have to engineer my own implentation of one of the interfaces (ISampleProvider, IWaveProvider etc, pretty sure it will somehow work going down an abstraction level)?

Thanks for any Input on this!

Answer (score 0):

The `MultiplexingWaveProvider` can do something close to what you want. Read about it [here](http://markheath.net/post/handling-multi-channel-audio-in-naudio). For 64 channel work you might find you need to write your own fine-tuned code as performance could become an issue.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the input, i will have a deeper look into the implementation. Generally after the ASIO driver access is opened, writing to the dedicated channelbuffers should not be a problem, right?

Comment: yes, best performance if you write directly to the buffers yourself